# Angular Schema Form - how to get rid of (success) text

Tags: angular-schema-form

I've used a formOptions of ["*"] as well as just [].  Whenever I type in valid data in a field the text "(success)" shows up next to the input.  How do I turn this off?  I don't see this in any of the examples and can't figure out what I'm doing differently.

Answer (score 1):

It is configurable, you can globally disable the success message:

https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form/blob/development/docs/index.md

> pristine  Object {errors ,success}:   Sets if errors and success states
>   should be visible when form field are $pristine. Default is {errors:
>   true, success: true}

you should set success: false

it is possible also to disable the success message locally as option of the form field:

```
-> disableSuccessState: true
```

standard options:

```
{
  key: "address.street",      // The dot notatin to the attribute on the model
  type: "text",               // Type of field
  title: "Street",            // Title of field, taken from schema if available
  notitle: false,             // Set to true to hide title
  description: "Street name", // A description, taken from schema if available, can be HTML
  validationMessage: "Oh noes, please write a proper address",  // A custom validation error message
  onChange: "valueChanged(form.key,modelValue)", // onChange event handler, expression or function
  feedback: false,             // Inline feedback icons
  disableSuccessState: false,  // Set true to NOT apply 'has-success' class to a field that was validated successfully
  disableErrorState: false,    // Set true to NOT apply 'has-error' class to a field that failed validation
  placeholder: "Input...",     // placeholder on inputs and textarea
  ngModelOptions: { ... },     // Passed along to ng-model-options
  readonly: true,              // Same effect as readOnly in schema. Put on a fieldset or array
                               // and their items will inherit it.
  htmlClass: "street foobar",  // CSS Class(es) to be added to the container div
  fieldHtmlClass: "street"     // CSS Class(es) to be added to field input (or similar)
  labelHtmlClass: "street"     // CSS Class(es) to be added to the label of the field (or similar)
  copyValueTo: ["address.street"],     // Copy values to these schema keys.
  condition: "person.age < 18" // Show or hide field depending on an angular expression
  destroyStrategy: "remove"    // One of "null", "empty" , "remove", or 'retain'. Changes model on $destroy event. default is "remove".
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: The following is not working - <div sf-schema="model.base.customSchema.jsonSchema" sf-form="model.base.formOptions" sf-model="model.base.customData" sf-options="{ pristine: { success: false }}"></div>.  I'm having to shove this in an old WebForms page, so I can't use a form tag.  I also tried formOptions = [{disableSuccessState: true}]; and that didn't work.  Is there any way to configure the form options to disable this for all keys?  I have an unknown number of keys from a user-generated schema.

Comment: can you please try sf-options="{ formDefaults: { ngModelOptions: { updateOn: 'blur' } }}" - you have also the option form.disableSuccessState = false in the form configuration

Comment: Still not working.  Here's a plunker demonstrating the issue.  It's basically the example from the ASF site - https://plnkr.co/edit/X90gRqnRMNbjWouLJJSu.  The reason I can't easily do disableSuccessState is because the schema is user-generated, and my form has to be able to handle any user's schema.  I could do it, but it would be a lot more work.

Comment: I don't get any success in the plunker.

Comment: See my answer explaining how I fixed it.

Comment: did you try to post the question in on the github? they are really responsive.

Comment: I talked with them on gitter, but was unable to get any of the ideas presented to work.  They are definitely responsive.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I came up with is to make sure the following style is added to the page.  This is how it is working in the Angular Schema Form example.  You can take a look in the following plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/X90gRqnRMNbjWouLJJSu.

```
.sr-only {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
    border: 0;
}
```

Change the name of that class and you'll see "(success)" come back whenever you type into the textboxes.  I think this is very hacky, but it's the only solution I've found.  In my scenario, I need a global solution. I cannot create form options for every single key because the schemas are user-generated.

I'd love to see a cleaner solution if someone can provide one.  Please don't just post an idea, try it in the Plunker and prove your idea works.  I've tried a lot of ideas, and the above style is the only one that works.